# How to read first 5000 images from a folder

Tags: matlab

```
path = dir(fullfile('G:\256_ObjectCategories\*\*.jpg'));
```

Here **Path** will contain the path of all images.
First * is to read all the 256 folders. The Each 256 folders contain 7k-8k images.
By writing ***.jpg**, it will read all the images, but I want to read first 5k images. How should I do that in **Matlab**?

Second Similar Question is

`data = imageDatastore(fullfile('G:\256_ObjectCategories')`

Now it will create an Image DataStore but again I want to read first 5k images from each 256 sub-folder present in super folder **256_ObjectCategories**.

How can I do it in Matlab?

Comment: How are you defining "first"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `imageDataStore` labeling and the `splitEachLabel` method ([see documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.spliteachlabel.html)).

> [imds1,imds2] = splitEachLabel(imds,p) splits the image files in imds
>   into two new datastores, imds1 and imds2. The new datastore imds1
>   contains the first p files from each label and imds2 contains the
>   remaining files from each label. p can be either a number between 0
>   and 1 indicating the percentage of the files from each label to assign
>   to imds1, or an integer indicating the absolute number of files from
>   each label to assign to imds1.

First create the data store automatically labeling each image with its folder name:

```
imds = imageDatastore('G:\256_ObjectCategories\*\*.jpg','LabelSource','foldernames');
```

Then you can split the datastore based on those labels like this:

```
[imds_5k, imds_extra] = splitEachLabel(imds,5000);
```

Now `imds_5k` will contain the first 5000 images from each folder (label), `imds_extra` will contain the other 2-3k images..

Answer (score 1):

There are many support forum from Matlab to do this job. Here is the example code from one of the forum of Matlab. I think this can solve your question

```
numFiles = length(myfile);
numRows = ceil(sqrt(numFiles));
for k = 1 : numFiles
    thisFileName = fullfile(myfile(k).folder, myfile(k).name);
    thisImage = imread(thisFileName);
    subplot(numRows, numRows, k);
    imshow(thisImage);
end
```